# Not able to find responsivity on datasheet of a PIN photodiode

Tags: photodiode

I am using a [VISHAY TEMD7000X01](http://www.vishay.com/doc?81951) as reference in doing a characterisation project of other tested PIN photodiode samples.

I expected to found the absolute responsivity on the datasheet but I cannot find on it.

Are there any methods to sort out this problem?

Comment: Try figure 3 in the data sheet.

Comment: Plus Figure 6 for other wavelengths besides 950 nm.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the datasheet (link edited into your question), most all the graphs on pages 2 and 3 are dedicated tk answering your exact question.

- Figure 3 shows absolute developed current vs. incident irradiance.
- Figure 4 shows the votage developed based on developed current.
- Figure 2 shows the effect of temperature on current output.
- Figure 6 shows the effect of incident light's wavelength on developed current.
- Figure 7 shows the directivity of the sensor/effect of incoming light's angle of incidence on the diode's ability to develop current from that light.

Those are the graphs that I found most poignant in finding the exact values you'll be wanting when using the diode as a reference standard.